# How can I do more than one level of cascading deletes in Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If I have a `Customers` table linked to an `Orders` table, and I want to delete a customer and its corresponding orders, then I can do:

```
dataContext.Orders.DeleteAllOnSubmit(customer.Orders);
dataContext.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(customer);
```

...which is great. However, what if I also have an `OrderItems` table, and I want to delete the order items for each of the orders deleted?

I can see how I could use `DeleteAllOnSubmit` to cause the deletion of all the order items for a *single* order, but how can I do it for *all* the orders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wish to consider using on delete cascade on the foreign key relationship in the database rather then using LINQ to do it.  If you wish to use LINQ then

```
customer.Orders.ForEach(x => x.OrderItems.ForEach(y=> dataContext.OrderItems.Delete(y));
dataContext.Orders.DeleteAllOnSubmit(customer.Orders);
dataContext.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(customer);
```

should do it but I haven't tested it.

Comment: How would that be translated into SQL? It looks like it's going to create a loop, whereas I would have hoped a JOIN could be used?

Comment: Also, you write "OrderItems.Delete" which seems different to the DeleteOnSubmit used on the other tables? Are the two compatible?